# Input.mousePosition.x is not working properly I cant't find the reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) || isStart)
    {
        isStart = true;
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime * 0.05f, 0, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
    }
}
```

When the game starts, when I click left on the screen, the object moves to the right instead of to the left. When I right click, it goes right again, but faster. As far as I understand, it considers the leftmost part of the screen as the middle, but why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Input.mousePosition.x` is a value that goes from 0 (leftmost) to `Screen.width` (rightmost) - see more on [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html).

This means that when you click on the left side your value is lower than when you click on the right side, this explains the speed change.

The range [0. `Scree.width`] is always positive, which means that your movement will always be in the same direction, this explains the object goes just to one side.

A simple solution is to divide your `Screen.width` by 2 and create a direction based on it.

```
var direction = Input.mousePosition.x < (Screen.width * .5f) ? -1 : 1;
transform.Translate(new Vector3(direction * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
```

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is for the object to follow the mouse. Your code doesn't work exactly the way I want it to. Thanks

Comment: Sure that don't, you didnt say what you want to achieve, just the problem, the solution is a bonus

Comment: Yes you are right.